# DRF Serializer empty OrderedDict on update()

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm using **Django 2.x** and **Django REST Framework**

```
class ComponentDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ComponentData
        fields = [
            'id',
            'analytics_type'
        ]


class ComponentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    data = ComponentDataSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Component
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'group',
            'data',
        ]

    def validate(self, attrs):
        print('validate data: {}'.format(attrs))
        return attrs
```

With `POST` request, the `attrs` in `validate()` is

```
validate data: OrderedDict([('name', 'Component Test'), ('group', <AnalyticsGroup: Chart>), ('data', [OrderedDict([('analytics_type', <AnalyticsType: Bar Chart>)])])])
```

While with `PATCH` request, the `data` attribute has empty `OrderedDict`

```
validate data: OrderedDict([('group', <AnalyticsGroup: Chart>), ('data', [OrderedDict()])])
```

The data payload in each request is the same.

```
name: "Component Test"
group: "2"
data[0]analytics_type: "3"
data[0]analytics_sub_type: "2"
data[0]query: "9"
```

Where value for each field `analytics_type`, `analytics_sub_type` and `query` is the `pk` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who stuck in the similar situation, The `PATCH` method with nested serializer works with the `JSON` data and not with the form data.

I passed `JSON` data instead of form data from postman and it's working.